# Building from source static bitcoind on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind, development, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to build bitcoind from source on Ubuntu 13.04:

```
$ apt-get install libboost-all-dev ccache pkg-config # deps
$ git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
$ cd bitcoin
$ ./configure --without-qt --with-incompatible-bdb
$ make
```

It works !

I'm looking for way to build static binary.

However, I can not find --enable-static option in configure. How should I build static bitcoind properly?

Answer (score 1):

You might ind useful these quote from *configure* docs

[Enabling static libraries for a package which consists of only dynamic modules makes no sense, and the package author would probably have decided to ignore such requests](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_85.html)

[... `AC_DISABLE_STATIC'
These macros tell libtool to not try and build either shared or static libraries respectively. libtool will always try to build something however, so even if you turn off static library building in 'configure.in', building your package for a target host without shared library support will fallback to building static archives.](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_86.html#SEC86)

In other words, check your code for presence of particular macro in configure.in files across subtree. it may have been decided to prevent making it static.